Use pfx certificate to get Microsoft Entra token - Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
I tried different ways to get an Azure AD token using a pfx certificate.
But the code below is persistently returning this error:
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
I also tried using @azure/keyvault-certificates and azure/identity, then genrating .pem files with open ssl, and in that case I also get the same error.
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const qs = require('querystring');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); 

const certPath = path.join(__dirname, 'certificate.pfx');
const certBuffer = fs.readFileSync(certPath);

const tokenEndpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id/oauth2/token';
const clientId = 'my-app-id';

const tokenPayload = {
    aud: tokenEndpoint,
    iss: clientId,
    sub: clientId,
    jti: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
    nbf: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600,
};

const tokenOptions = {
    algorithm: 'RS256',
};

const clientAssertion = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, certBuffer, tokenOptions);
console.log('Client Assertion:', clientAssertion);

const postData = {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: clientId,
    resource: 'resource',
    client_assertion: clientAssertion,
    client_assertion_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer',
};

const axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        pfx: certBuffer,
        passphrase: '',
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
    }),
};

async function getToken() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, qs.stringify(postData), axiosConfig);
        const token = response.data.access_token;
        console.log('Token:', token);
        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Error response from Azure AD:', error.response.data);
        }
        throw error;
    }
}

getToken().then(token => {
    console.log('Token:', token);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to obtain token:', err);
});


In my case, I ran below OpenSSL commands to create private key and certificate like this:
openssl genrsa -out sridemo.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key sridemo.pem -out sridemo.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in sridemo.csr -signkey sridemo.pem -out sridemo.crt

Response:

Make sure to upload sridemo.crt file to your Entra ID app registration and note thumbprint value:

To generate Microsoft Entra token using certificate, I used @azure/msal-node with below sample code:
const fs = require('fs');
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');

const tenantId = 'tenant_id';
const clientId = 'appId';
const authority = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`;
const certPath = 'path/to/your/certificate.pem';
const certThumbprint = 'cert_thumbprint';
const scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';

// Read the certificate
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(certPath, 'utf8');

const confidentialClientConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        authority: authority,
        clientCertificate: {
            thumbprint: certThumbprint,
            privateKey: privateKey,
        },
    },
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(confidentialClientConfig);

// Acquire a token
async function getToken() {
    try {
        const tokenResponse = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
            scopes: [scope],
        });
        console.log('Access Token:', tokenResponse.accessToken);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error acquiring token:', error);
    }
}

getToken();

Response:

To confirm that, you can decode the token in jwt.ms and check claims as below:

Reference:
MSAL NODE · AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js (github.com)

thank you, I will follow your sample and also will check the reference.
In my case I already have the cert in an azure keyvault, and I'm downloading it to the local machine as .pfx file, then I generate the .pem file with this openssl command.
$opensslCommand = "openssl pkcs12 -in $tempFilePath -out $pemFilePath -nodes -passin pass:"

I tried but the I get this error when uploadind the crt to my app registration; "Failed to add certificate. Error detail: Credential is not issued by a trusted certificate authority as per assigned policy.". Could be possible to use the existing .pfx cert file from my keyvault?

Alternatively, download certificate from Azure Key Vault as .cer file and upload it to Azure AD application. Refer this https://medium.com/@shekhartarare/create-self-signed-certificate-using-azure-key-vault-69a91ee06530

it worked by uploading the .cer file, thank you
